# Query the sum of all price totals, to create leaderboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to create a leaderboard for highest sum of purchases. Every `Purchase` has a `user_id` and a `price`.  Every Purchase, belongs_to a User. We want to query all the purchases, group the records by user_id, and sum the `price` totals. I have tried a million things. The closest I've been able to come is

`Purchase.joins(:user).select('users.*, sum(price) as total').group('user_id'). order('total DESC').limit(20)`

which returns the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  users.*, sum(price) as total FROM "purchase...`

I'm running PostgreSQL 9 and Rails 3. Any and all help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just show me the full select query(_am not a ror developer_ :)) ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `users.id` in group clause instead of `user_id`.

Try this:

```
Purchase.joins(:user).select('users.*, sum(price) as total').group('users.id').order('total DESC').limit(20)
```

Comment: I had tried that yesterday too -- it returns an array, but the response doesn't include any of the values I need: ` [#<Purchase id: 2, created_at: "2012-02-29 11:12:20", updated_at: "2015-03-25 23:25:54">, #<Purchase id: 129157, created_at: "2013-05-19 20:24:56", updated_at: "2014-12-27 05:38:19">].` Frankly, I'm not sure what this response means, as there isn't even a `Purchase` with `id` 129157 in the database.